# Array char not read properly

Tags: c, arrays, character

I don't know why the values at these array indices are not displayed properly

```
       char tris[3][3]={
           {33, 33, 33,},
           {33, 33, 33,},
           {33, 33, 33,}};
           printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[1][1], tris[1][2], tris[1][3]);
           printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[2][1], tris[2][2], tris[2][3]);
           printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[3][1], tris[3][2], tris[3][3]);
```

The output is this thing and some other strange characters

```
> !|!|!
  !|!|
```

Comment: Arrays are 0 base indexed.  So range goes 0 to 2 and not 1 to 3

Answer (score 1):

Correct, there was already the right answer. The index starts at 0.

```
   char tris[3][3]={
       {33, 33, 33,},
       {33, 33, 33,},
       {33, 33, 33,}};
       printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[0][0], tris[0][1], tris[0][2]);
       printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[1][0], tris[1][1], tris[1][2]);
       printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[2][0], tris[2][2], tris[2][2]);
       }
```

BTW: Do you intentionally wrote an int 33 in the char? Or do you wanted '33'?

Comment: `'33'` has a value that exceeds the range of `char`.  Unlikely OP wanted that.

Comment: Yes, It does. Just wanted to check - sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your program has two issues:

1. Array indexing starts at `0`, not `1`. The only exception is the definition of the amount of elements to hold in a certain dimension at the declaration of `tris`.

With using `3` for any dimension you invoke undefined behavior, because you attempt to read from locations outside of the 2D array.

Rather use:

```
printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[0][0], tris[0][1], tris[0][2]);
printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[1][0], tris[1][1], tris[1][2]);
printf("%c|%c|%c\n", tris[2][0], tris[2][1], tris[2][2]);
```

2. > "*The output is this thing and some strange characters.*"

This is because the ASCII number `33` corresponds to the `'!'` character.

If you want to print the integer `33` instead you should use the `%d` conversion specifier for printing integral values instead of the `%c` conversion specifier to printing actual characters in the `printf()` call.

---

Corrected program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char tris[3][3]= {
                      {33, 33, 33,},
                      {33, 33, 33,},
                      {33, 33, 33,}
                    };

   printf("%d|%d|%d\n", tris[0][0], tris[0][1], tris[0][2]);
   printf("%d|%d|%d\n", tris[1][0], tris[1][1], tris[1][2]);
   printf("%d|%d|%d\n", tris[2][0], tris[2][1], tris[2][2]);
}
```

Output:

```
33|33|33
33|33|33
33|33|33
```

---

Side note:

If `tris` has no explicit character intention, you shall declare it as of type `int[][]` instead of `char[][]`:

```
int tris[3][3]= {
                   {33, 33, 33,},
                   {33, 33, 33,},
                   {33, 33, 33,}
                };
```